# W7 Login to Secure Sites [only] are Very Slow

Tags: windows-7, login, internet, website

I hope this is the right place to post this.

Have a notebook PC that customer bought with W7 Home, and they brought it to me to have it put on their network.  We installed a retail Windows 7 Pro (one we had on the shelf) and everything is fine EXCEPT:

Logins to the secure pages of certain websites (mostly vendor sites) are crazy slow, taking a couple minutes or even five minutes at times.  Other PCs in the office can login to these same sites and the logins require at most a second or two.  Accessing the http: portions of the sites are normal speed, but on attempting login to the secure (usually vendor order pages) portion of the site, they think it has locked up (but in due time the login generally completes).

We are seeing no signs of any problems from other workstations, however, this particular one has to be used in this office.

I have tried this process with firewall and MSE disabled an still no progress.  I have added the sites to the "Trusted" sites in Internet Options.  I have actually replaced the NIC with a different type to rule out a problem with NIC drivers.  Network/Internet is otherwise normal speed on this workstation.

So, I've checked pretty much everything I know to check.  Question is this: Can anyone make a suggestion as to possible sources of this problem?  I am particularly interested in whether there could be any policy settings causing this.  Also, problem seems the same whether we're using IE or Chrome.

TIA for any suggestions.

Comment: This seems like more of a question for http://superuser.com/, but it may be network related.  Is this new computer a member of the domain? Are the workstations? Do you use any sort of web proxy? If yes, how are the client machines configured for it?

Comment: Answer what @Neil asked and also check the time and date of the PC.

Comment: New PC is on the domain and users can access domain resources with no difficulty.  All workstations are on the domain, except for two that form a private workgroup between those two.  No proxy is used; the workstations point to the 2003 Server as DNS, and  name resolution seems to work fine.

Comment: System time on server and the problem workstation is correct as is timezone (man, I was hoping that was it!).